The visa expiration date on my German D type Student visa is subsequent to my intended dates of stay
I am going to Germany on a DAAD funded internship from 01-09-2024 to 31-03-2025. I applied for a National visa (D type) with the same dates in my VIDEX form. I got the visa but the visa expiration date is 31-08-2025. The DAAD letter of award specifies the duration mentioned above.Is this a problem ? Whom should I contact if that is the case?

I read that your internship runs from 1st of September 2024 till 31st of March 2025. Your visa runs till 31st of August 2025, so I do not see your problem. Is my reading of the dates wrong?

To be clear, are you asking if it’s a problem that your visa expires 5 months after your internship ends? It is valid for the period of your internship, at the end of which you will presumably intend to return to your country of residence.. What problem do you see?

It’s common in many countries that visas beyond a few days/weeks have fixed durations such as 6 months, 1 year, 2 years, 5 years… absolutely nothing surprising about a one-year visa IMHO.

Thanks for all the comments. I was worried that they misprinted or something and I may get questioned as to why I applied for longer duration if my internship funding ends well before that.
